# Integration of Cheetahmail API with MVC4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, email

I want to integrate my website, which built on MVC4, with Cheetahmail API for sending auto generated mails to the users. I failed to find any samples/ ideas to integrate cheetahmail. Someone could provide me sample codes/links for Cheetahmail integration?